# Android: Change image on many imageviews when clicked/active

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, selector

I have noticed many similar answers but unfortunately I'm having trouble using any of them. I am a few different imageviews as buttons:

```
    ImageView filterWorld = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_world);
    filterWorld.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this) ) ;

    ImageView filterSports = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_sports);
    filterSports.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this)  ) ;

    ImageView filterEconomy = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_economy);
    filterEconomy.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this)  ) ;
```

Each of them is using an **xml selector** as resource, such as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/world_active" android:state_selected="true">
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/world_active" android:state_focused="true">
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/world_active" android:state_pressed="true">
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/filter_white_world">
</item>
```

And the layout xml:

```
       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/filter_world"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/world"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        />
```

But the problem is that every button remains on "active" state only when it is clicked, and not when spesific content is shown. Also I would like each button to **return to its default state when another button is clicked**.
Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
with your help I have managed to make the button change on every click, but now the content does not change. There seems to be a colfict between the onclick listeners. Here is my code:

```
    final ImageView filterWorld = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_world);
    filterWorld.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this) ) ;

    final ImageView filterSports = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_sports);
    filterSports.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this)  ) ;

filterWorld.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filterWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.world_active);
            filterSports.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_sports); }
    });

filterSports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filterWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);
            filterSports.setImageResource(R.drawable.sports_active); }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by active state?

Comment: By the clikc of each button different content is displayed. By active state, I mean, as long as no other button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using selecter..
simply implement the click listner on each imageview.

and change the backround resource on all imageview.

```
filterWorld.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filterWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.world_active);
            filterSport.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);
            filterEconomy.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);               
       }
    });

filterSport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filterSport.setImageResource(R.drawable.world_active);
            filterWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);
            filterEconomy.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);               
       }
    });


filterEconomy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            filterEconomy.setImageResource(R.drawable.world_active);
            filterSport.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);
            filterWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.filter_white_world);               
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution but in the filterWorld.setOnClickListene, filterSport and filterEconomy cannot be resolved.

Comment: filterWorld,filterSport and filterEconomy are the objects of your imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

When you press a button, it will go to active state and you have to set it to default state when an another button is pressed. 
So set buttons other than which is currently pressed to default state by using this

```
 ImageView filterWorld = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_world);
 filterWorld.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this)
 filterSports.setSelected(false);
 filterSports.setPressed(false);
 filterEconomy.setSelected(false);
 filterEconomy.setPressed(false);
 ) ;
```